# Function for get products on sale

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How to get products on sale?
The class `Product`not have a function for this.

I have try to add a new method in Product override class, but doesn't return any product (I'm a noob in prestashop code).

```
    /**
    * Get new products
    *
    * @param integer $id_lang Language id
    * @param integer $pageNumber Start from (optional)
    * @param integer $nbProducts Number of products to return (optional)
    * @return array New products
    */
    public static function getOnSaleProducts($id_lang, $page_number = 0, $nb_products = 10,
        $count = false, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        if (!$context)
            $context = Context::getContext();

        $front = true;
        if (!in_array($context->controller->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront')))
            $front = false;

        if ($page_number < 0) $page_number = 0;
        if ($nb_products < 1) $nb_products = 10;
        if (empty($order_by) || $order_by == 'position') $order_by = 'date_add';
        if (empty($order_way)) $order_way = 'DESC';
        if ($order_by == 'id_product' || $order_by == 'price' || $order_by == 'date_add'  || $order_by == 'date_upd')
            $order_by_prefix = 'p';
        else if ($order_by == 'name')
            $order_by_prefix = 'pl';
        if (!Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || !Validate::isOrderWay($order_way))
            die(Tools::displayError());

        $groups = FrontController::getCurrentCustomerGroups();
        $sql_groups = (count($groups) ? 'IN ('.implode(',', $groups).')' : '= 1');
        if (strpos($order_by, '.') > 0)
        {
            $order_by = explode('.', $order_by);
            $order_by_prefix = $order_by[0];
            $order_by = $order_by[1];
        }
        if ($count)
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.`id_product`) AS nb
                    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                    '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                    WHERE product_shop.`active` = 1
                    AND p.`on_sale` = true
                    AND DATEDIFF(
                        product_shop.`date_add`,
                        DATE_SUB(
                            NOW(),
                            INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY
                        )
                    ) > 0
                    '.($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '').'
                    AND p.`id_product` IN (
                        SELECT cp.`id_product`
                        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg
                        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)
                        WHERE cg.`id_group` '.$sql_groups.'
                    )';
            return (int)Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($sql);
        }

        $sql = new DbQuery();
        $sql->select(
            'p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`,
            pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, image_shop.`id_image`, il.`legend`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name,
            DATEDIFF(
                product_shop.`date_add`,
                DATE_SUB(
                    NOW(),
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY
                )
            ) > 0 AS new'
        );

        $sql->from('product', 'p');
        $sql->join(Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p'));
        $sql->leftJoin('product_lang', 'pl', '
            p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
            AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl')
        );
        $sql->leftJoin('image', 'i', 'i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`');
        $sql->join(Shop::addSqlAssociation('image', 'i'));
        $sql->leftJoin('image_lang', 'il', 'i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang);
        $sql->leftJoin('manufacturer', 'm', 'm.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`');

        $sql->where('p.`on_sale` = true');
        $sql->where('product_shop.`active` = 1');
        $sql->where('(image_shop.id_image IS NOT NULL OR i.id_image IS NULL) OR (image_shop.id_image IS NULL AND i.cover=1)');
        if ($front)
            $sql->where('product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")');

        $sql->where('p.`id_product` IN (
            SELECT cp.`id_product`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)
            WHERE cg.`id_group` '.$sql_groups.')'
        );

        $sql->orderBy((isset($order_by_prefix) ? pSQL($order_by_prefix).'.' : '').'`'.pSQL($order_by).'` '.pSQL($order_way));
        $sql->limit($nb_products, $page_number * $nb_products);

        $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);

        if ($order_by == 'price')
            Tools::orderbyPrice($result, $order_way);
        if (!$result)
            return false;

        $products_ids = array();
        foreach ($result as $row)
            $products_ids[] = $row['id_product'];
        // Thus you can avoid one query per product, because there will be only one query for all the products of the cart
        Product::cacheFrontFeatures($products_ids, $id_lang);

        return Product::getProductsProperties((int)$id_lang, $result);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are going to have to limit the question a bit. Try dumping the generated SQL and running it via phpMyAdmin or something similiar. Is it actually being called? What code soes it run, try adding some echo's so you know what is runnig and what is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
/**
* Get products 'on sale'
*
* @param integer $id_lang Language id
* @param integer $pageNumber Start from (optional)
* @param integer $nbProducts Number of products to return (optional)
* @return array New products
*/
public static function getOnSaleProducts($id_lang, $page_number = 0, $nb_products = 10,
    $count = false, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, Context $context = null)
{
    if (!$context)
        $context = Context::getContext();

    $front = true;
    if (!in_array($context->controller->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront')))
        $front = false;

    if ($page_number < 0) $page_number = 0;
    if ($nb_products < 1) $nb_products = 10;
    if (empty($order_by) || $order_by == 'position') $order_by = 'date_add';
    if (empty($order_way)) $order_way = 'DESC';
    if ($order_by == 'id_product' || $order_by == 'price' || $order_by == 'date_add'  || $order_by == 'date_upd')
        $order_by_prefix = 'p';
    else if ($order_by == 'name')
        $order_by_prefix = 'pl';
    if (!Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || !Validate::isOrderWay($order_way))
        die(Tools::displayError());

    $groups = FrontController::getCurrentCustomerGroups();
    $sql_groups = (count($groups) ? 'IN ('.implode(',', $groups).')' : '= 1');
    if (strpos($order_by, '.') > 0)
    {
        $order_by = explode('.', $order_by);
        $order_by_prefix = $order_by[0];
        $order_by = $order_by[1];
    }
    if ($count)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.`id_product`) AS nb
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                WHERE product_shop.`active` = 1
                AND p.`on_sale` = true
                AND DATEDIFF(
                    product_shop.`date_add`,
                    DATE_SUB(
                        NOW(),
                        INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY
                    )
                ) > 0
                '.($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '').'
                AND p.`id_product` IN (
                    SELECT cp.`id_product`
                    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg
                    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)
                    WHERE cg.`id_group` '.$sql_groups.'
                )';
        return (int)Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($sql);
    }

    $sql = new DbQuery();
    $sql->select(
        'p.*, product_shop.*, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`,
        pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, image_shop.`id_image`, il.`legend`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name,
        DATEDIFF(
            product_shop.`date_add`,
            DATE_SUB(
                NOW(),
                INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY
            )
        ) > 0 AS new'
    );

    $sql->from('product', 'p');
    $sql->join(Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p'));
    $sql->leftJoin('product_lang', 'pl', '
        p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
        AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl')
    );
    $sql->leftJoin('image', 'i', 'i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`');
    $sql->join(Shop::addSqlAssociation('image', 'i', false, 'image_shop.cover=1'));
    $sql->leftJoin('image_lang', 'il', 'i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang);
    $sql->leftJoin('manufacturer', 'm', 'm.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`');

    $sql->where('p.on_sale = true');
    $sql->where('product_shop.`active` = 1');
    $sql->where('(image_shop.id_image IS NOT NULL OR i.id_image IS NULL) OR (image_shop.id_image IS NULL AND i.cover=1)');
    if ($front)
        $sql->where('product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")');

    $sql->where('p.`id_product` IN (
        SELECT cp.`id_product`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)
        WHERE cg.`id_group` '.$sql_groups.')'
    );

    $sql->orderBy((isset($order_by_prefix) ? pSQL($order_by_prefix).'.' : '').'`'.pSQL($order_by).'` '.pSQL($order_way));
    $sql->limit($nb_products, $page_number * $nb_products);

    $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);

    // return $sql->build(); die();
    if ($order_by == 'price')
        Tools::orderbyPrice($result, $order_way);
    if (!$result)
        return false;


    $products_ids = array();
    foreach ($result as $row)
        $products_ids[] = $row['id_product'];
    // Thus you can avoid one query per product, because there will be only one query for all the products of the cart
    Product::cacheFrontFeatures($products_ids, $id_lang);

    return Product::getProductsProperties((int)$id_lang, $result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should do a search for the class `ProductSaleCore` in ProductSale.php.
It looks like what you are seeking.

Comment: that class doesn't have a method for return products thar is 'on sale'